# Post Feed data modeling in Swift

Tags: swift, polymorphism, protocols, data-modeling

This question is about the best way to store an array of posts for a news feed (Like Twitter/Facebook/whatever) when you have several types of posts. To make things simpler, let's consider a situation when you have 2 types of posts (each with a different cell UI) : a "big" post (with photos, text ... ) and an "small" post, that serves more like a notification. If you wanna present both kinds of posts in an UI element (collectionView / tableView) is handy to have then both in a "posts" array, so we can do something like this:

```
    protocol Post { 
        var postID : String {get set}
        var creatorID : String {get set}
        var postType : PostType {get set} //<--- Custom enum that just has ".big" and ".small" in this case
        //some other general things for the post may go here
    }

    struct BigPost : Post {
       //All the post vars here
       var postID : String 
       var creatorID : String 
       var postType : PostType = .big

       //Some other things for this post type (just examples, they are not important)
        var imageUrl : String
        var countComments : Int
        //etc
    }

     struct SmallPost : Post {
       //All the post vars here
       var postID : String 
       var creatorID : String 
       var postType : PostType = .small

       //Some other things for this post type (just examples, they are not important)
        var text : String
        //etc
    }
```

If you do that, you can actually do this

```
   var posts : [Post] = [BigPost(), SmallPost(), SmallPost(), BigPost()]
```

And it works, you just need to dequeuque the corresponding cell for each post type using the "postType" var. My question is, is this a **good** way to do it? Because I thought about implementing diffing (witch, for example, deepDiff, that is awesome https://github.com/onmyway133/DeepDiff ) , so the update in the collectionView/tableView is efficient when we have a lot of posts, but then, how would I do it? Because I can't make my Post protocol conform to some other "Diffable" protocol, because then I could not declare an array of type [Post], and even if I made both, smallPost and bigPosts, conform to that "Diffable" protocol, I the elements in the "post" array are still treated as "Post" by the compiler, so I could not execute any "diff".

Maybe some strategie with polymorphism is better? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Type Casting - https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html

You can made smallPost and bigPost conform "Diffable", create array

```
var posts : [Diffable] = [BigPost(), SmallPost(), SmallPost(), BigPost()]
```

And then check their types:

```
if let post = posts[0] as? SmallPost {
   // do something
}
```

or

```
if let post = posts[0] as? BigPost {
   // do something
}
```

And you dont need additional property for that (var postType : PostType {get set})

Comment: Nice approach, but sadly in this case you can't do that, since "Diffable" normally  has associated types (in the particular case of DeepDiff, the protocol name is DiffAware and also has an associated type), so you can't make arrays out of that, you get the annoying "Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint" error